# Edit dynamic List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

```
List<object> Lst =  obj.GetAllTravelRequestForGrid(DateTime.Parse(TxtFromDate.Text),DateTime.Parse(TxtToDate.Text), int.Parse(DDLEmployee.SelectedValue), RdoTravelStatus.SelectedValue);

foreach (object o in Lst)
{
    string DocUrl = "";
    int TravelID = 0; int TravelSubID = 0;
    int DocUrlIndex = 0; int TraveilDIndex = 0; int TravelSubIDIndex = 0;

    Type t = o.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();

    DocUrlIndex = 12;

    TraveilDIndex = 0;
    TravelID = int.Parse(pi[0].GetValue(o).ToString());

    TravelSubIDIndex = 1;
    TravelSubID = int.Parse(pi[1].GetValue(o).ToString());

    DLL.mySetuiDEntities db = new DLL.mySetuiDEntities();
    DocUrl = string.Join(",", db.HR_TravelDocuments.Where(i => i.TravelID == TravelID && i.TravelSubID == TravelSubID).ToList());

    string Test = pi[12].GetValue(o).ToString();
    pi[12].SetValue(o, DocUrl, null); 
}
```

Error at last line `SetValue` throws

> Property set method not found

Comment: Why not just use `pi[12].SetValue(o, DocUrl);`?

Comment: The error message seems straightforward. The property you are trying to set doesn't have a setter. Do you think it should? And why on earth are you getting the property by index? I would be surprised if `GetProperties` guaranteed an ordering for its results.

Comment: what is the property pi[12] ?
I agree with Chris and i'm really confident in using GetProperties like this...

Comment: Can you explain why you need a `List<object>` instead of a list containing something with a stronger type, or even `dynamic`?